# Error while deplying a ML model using Flask and Docker - NameError: name 'cosine_distances' is not defined

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, flask, scikit-learn

I have created a KNN model using KNeighborsClassifier from scikit-learn. The model definition:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(weights='distance', metric=lambda v1, v2: cosine_distances([v1], [v2])[0])

knn.fit(title_vectors, titles)
```

After fitting, the model was saved using pickle (a python library).

```
import dill as pickle

filename = 'knn_model.sav'
pickle.dump(knn, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

The saved model was then loaded to predict the outcome.

```
import dill as pickle

new_job_desc = "software engineer"

vector = sent2vect(new_job_desc)

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
loaded_model.predict(vector.reshape(1, -1))
```

The whole process works fine when it was built locally. But when I try to deploy the same procedure using docker, It shows the following error:

```
NameError: name 'cosine_distances' is not defined
```

Total error log:

```
  warnings.warn(
[2023-04-10 06:48:09,240] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/job-ai/app.py", line 74, in extract
    output = loaded_model.predict(vector.reshape(1, -1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py", line 237, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py", line 861, in kneighbors
    chunked_results = list(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1867, in pairwise_distances_chunked
    D_chunk = pairwise_distances(X_chunk, Y, metric=metric, n_jobs=n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 2039, in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1579, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1623, in _pairwise_callable
    out[i, j] = metric(X[i], Y[j], **kwds)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_20/3568926769.py", line -1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'cosine_distances' is not defined
```

I have tried multiple approach to solve this problem. I have used different versions of python, scikit-learn and recreated the whole process using a virtual environment multiple time. Still, the problem is not resolving. I have searched everywhere for a related solution. But I was unable to find any.